# Visualizing data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize the population per year in R with a ggplot.

I would like to have years on the x axis and population on the Y axis.

Have the following code:

```
    df <- read.csv("http://www.statistikdatabasen.scb.se/sq/13965", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".",stringsAsFactor=F)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=year))+geom_bar()
```

Any suggestions how i can proceed?

Comment: First, please read (1) [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), (2) [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as (3) [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., provide input data & the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the identity in the `geom_bar`

Try this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= year, y=Population)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="dark blue")
```

Then I would suggest to fix the axis.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html) of **ggplot**:

> If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data,
>   use stat="identity" and map a value to the y aesthetic.

```
ggplot(df, aes(year,Population)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```